# Change detection doesn't fire in setTimeout with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: angular

I have two components, where I use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush. A parent component:

```js
    @Component({
     changeStaregy: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
     template:`
        <button (click)="onClick()">clear</button>
        <div>
            <test [model]="model"></test>
        </div>`
    })
    export class AppComponent {
        model: TestModel;
        
        constructor(){
          this.model = { id: 1, text: 'bla bla bla'}
        }
    
        onClick() {
          this.model = new TestModel();
        }
    }
```

and a child component that just displays a data:

```js
    @Component({
       changeStrategy: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
       selector: 'test',
       template: `
        <div>
              <div> {{model.id}} </div>
               <div> {{model.text}} </div>
        </div>`
    })
    
    export class TestComponent {
       @Input() model: TestModel;
       
    }
```

When I click on the button "clear", it calls onClick() function, which assigns an empty entity to "model". This triggers a change detection, because the input was changed (OnPush strategy). But if I wrap assignment with an async call, the change detection doesn't work and therefore UI is not updated:

```js
    onClick() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.model = new TestModel();
      }, 2000);
    }
```

Angular2+ has NgZone which patches a setTimeout function. The patched setTimeout must trigger the change detection, but in my case it doesn't. Why the change detection doen't work? How can I fix it?

Comment: that's actually very weird, can you create a simple plunker? I'll take a look

Comment: Made a plunker, strange behavior https://plnkr.co/edit/V5jcTlA2c1wwjUTEdVMA?p=preview

Answer (score 6):

Because the `changeDetectionStrategy` is set to `OnPush` on the parent, the change detection cycle stops at the parent element. As a result any child of this parent will have the strategy set to `OnPush`, regardless of its own setting.

No `@Input` of the parent changes, and therefor the change detector doesn't go in any deeper towards the childs of the parent. You should execute a `detectChanges` to have the changes take effect

Comment: But it works without setTimeout and setTimeout is running in the zone.

Comment: @AlbertGore Thats because the click marks the component für change detection. With setTimeout the change is delayed until after the change detection happened.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it. The child's @Input changes (namely the reference, not only a property). Shouldn't that trigger it's own change detection cycle even in OnPush strategy?

Comment: @StefanHolzapfel But the change is done from a parent which is onPush. That should work, but the change is inside a cycle which is not 'supported' by OnPush. Only a native DOM event can trigger it, or a manual markForCheck. That's why removing the setTimeout and just doing it inside a click works

Answer (score 6):

Here are the steps as to what is happening in your scenario:

1. The bound click event will mark the component and its ancestors as dirty when triggered. This happens before the `onClick()` method is executed.
2. After the `onClick()` method executes, Angular calls `ApplicationRef.tick()` to kick off change detection. Because the ancestor components were marked as dirty, change detection happens on your OnPush components. Keep in mind that at this point, the setTimeout callback hasn't executed yet.
3. After change detection completes, the components are no longer 'dirty'.
   The setTimeout callback then executes. After the setTimeout callback completes, ApplicationRef.tick() is called to kick off change detection again.
   However, because your AppComponent is marked with OnPush, and there is no `@Input` change (because AppComponent has no Inputs), and component and its ancestors aren't marked as dirty, Change detection won't go through to the child component. So the change to `this.model` won't be reflected in the DOM.

I found this helpful:
https://www.mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need

Answer (score 1):

When using OnPush change detection strategy, change detection only runs when an input property changes, bound event is trigger from component or you manually detect changes.

In your example plunker the child component changes input by itself in `changeSetTimeout` and `changeModelInZone`.

When you click on the button second time bounded event is triggered due to which template is updated.

Comment: That is true for the plunker. But in the original question the @Input is changed from parent?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a promise to keep Change Detection working.

```
  onDoSometing() {
   this.changeVariable = -1; // sample immediate change

   this.timeout(3000).then(v => {
    this.changeVariable = 2; //sample, put your code here
   });
  }



  timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
```

Comment: I had this issue even with the Default change detection. This answer fixed the problem.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem (Angular 16). It seems there is no good solution for this in Angular for async methods that are not http calls